# Need help with a calculus question on finding the minimum of a value

Tags: calculus

I came across a question from a Standardized Test.

The reference is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/College_Scholastic_Ability_Test#Mathematics_2

I would like to summarize the problem as follows:
given a function $f(x)$ defined on $x>a$ and a quartic function $g(x)$ whose leading coefficient is $-1$. These two satisfy the below conditions:

1. $\forall x > a$ $\in$ $R$, $(x-a)f(x) = g(x)$,
2. $f(x)$ attains local maxima at $\alpha,\beta$ $\in$ $R$, whose value is $M$,
3. $f(x)$ has more local extrema than $g(x)$ does.

$\beta-\alpha=6\sqrt3$. Find the minimum of $M$.

My strategy is that I will find $f(x)$ and $\alpha$ in terms of $a$, then substitute to get $f(\alpha)=M$ in terms of $a$; after that I solve $\frac{dM}{da}=0$ to find the extrema.

My attempt is as follow:

Let
$$g(x) = -x^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e,$$
$$g'(x) = -4x^3 + 3bx^2 + 2cx + d$$

From (1), we have:
$$
f(x) = g(x)/(x-a)
$$

After taking the first derivative and arrage the terms, we have:
$$
f'(x) = \frac
  {-5x^4 + 4(b+a)x^3 + 3(c-ba)x^2 + 2(d-ca)x + (e+da)}
  {(x-a)^2}
$$

From here I am stuck.

I cannot simplify using the second condition, which is
$$
f'(\alpha)=f'(\alpha+6\sqrt3)=0,
$$
$$
\frac{g(\alpha)}{(\alpha-a)}=\frac{g(\alpha+6\sqrt3)}{(\alpha+6\sqrt3-a)}
$$
since the complexity of the expansion was getting out of hand.

Furthermore, using the third condition, it implies that $f'$ has more distinct roots than $g'$ does. As deduced above, $f'(x)=0$ will have at most 4 distinct roots and at least 2 distinct roots, while $g'(x)=0$ has at most 3 distinct roots and at least 1 root. $f$ has two maxima from (2). Then $f'(x)=0$ must have at least 2 distinct roots. I am unable to deduce further to get to anything meaningful.

Would you give me some pointers on the question and point out where I went wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, it meant $g'(x)=0$ has at least 1 root and at most 3 distinct roots

Comment: edited. Thanks a lot

Comment: since $f'(x)$ is a quadratic, $g'(x)=0$ has at most one root

Comment: Would you please elaborate on this? Thanks

Comment: $g(x)$ is quartic, no? Which means $f(x)$ is a cubic

Comment: Not only is not only cubic but the leading coefficient must also be -1. This comes from the g(x) = (x-a) f(x) requirement.

Comment: @AdamNeeley: Condition # 3 implies that $g'(x)$ has fewer roots than $f'(x)$

Comment: Oof, thanks @Vasya. Could the fact that the function evaluated at the endpoints its domain are also considered to be its local extremum have something to do with it?

Comment: @AdamNeeley: Yes, it has to be an interval bounded on the left, otherwise it's impossible to have two maxima

Comment: I'm confused. $g$ has a power of 4, so $g'$ has a power of 3, so $f'$ has a power of 2, so why wouldn't $f$ have 3 local extrema if it's bounded on the left? @Vasya

Comment: quadratic has at most two roots so cubic has at most two local extrema on all reals

Comment: @Vasya As I follow your argument, I've arrived at $\alpha=a$, is it correct? If so, would it contradict with the fact that $f$ is undefined at $a$? I'm confused.

Comment: @Bathah: That's not necessarily true, we can definitely say that $a < \alpha$